# Grabbing new channel ID from json file in background task

Tags: discord.py

I have a background task that send a message in a channel that the channel ID is stored in JSON. In the even that channel gets deleted, a new channel ID replaces the old channel ID in the JSON file. I'm getting `discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10003): Unknown Channel` when the background task sends again. I tried to put the piece of code `chanid = get_general()` outside of the background task code in hopes that it pulls in the new channel ID in the loop but I feel like I a missing something here.

```
try:
    with open("channels.json", 'r') as fp:
        channels = json.load(fp)
except Exception:
    channels = {}

def save_channels():
    with open("channels.json", "w+") as fp:
        json.dump(channels, fp, indent=4)

def get_general():
    return channels.get("general", 0)

chanid = get_general()

async def hello_loop():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    chan = client.get_channel(chanid)
    while not client.is_closed():
        msg= 'hello'
        msgsend = await chan.send(msg)

client.loop.create_task(hello_loop())
```

Answer (score 0):

What I need is, on chance that a delete channel command is used, I remove the current general channel ID inside of delete channel command and replace it with the cloned channel ID. I also stop the background task, and reset it within the same command. It works the way I want it, but maybe there is a better way of approaching it?

Comment: Seems like you have answered your own question.. Please edit your question.